# Combinatorial question regarding size of subsets of pairs

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Question: I have $l$ pairs $(x,y)$ with $x,y \in \{ 1,2,...,n \}$. How many different elements (in $ \{ 1,...n\}$) do we  at least see among these pairs (depending on $l$)?

for example I tried to say if we have $k\cdot n$ many different elements that occur then we can form at most $(k \cdot n)^2$ couples with these elements. So we have to set $(k \cdot n)^2 \geq l$ and from there we get $k$ and finally the least number of different elements we need to form $l$ pairs. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

With $k$ pairwise different elements we can create $k^2$ different pairs.

> If $l\geq 1$ pairs are given, the smallest number of different elements which are contained in $l$ pairs is the number
>
> \begin{array}{lll}
> &k\qquad &\text{if } k^2=l&\\
> &k+1\qquad &\text{if } k^2<l<(k+1)^2&
> \end{array}
>
> which can be expressed compactly according to @BrianMScott's comment as $$\left\lceil\sqrt{l}\right\rceil$$

$\lceil x\rceil$ is denoting the *[ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)* of $x$.

Comment: Which can be expressed compactly as $\left\lceil\sqrt{\ell}\right\rceil$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I thought about three minutes if it is helpful to additionally introduce the ceiling function. Your comment smoothed the way to do so, thanks. :-)

Comment: My pleasure. I figured that it can’t hurt to have both forms.